# Import cycle with Model, ModelManager and ModelSerializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am using Django with Django Rest Framework for serializers.

I have the following situation.

In file `models.py`:

```
from django.db.models import Manager, Model, CharField

from .serializers import MyModelSerializer


class MyModelManager(Manager):
    serializer_class = MyModelSerializer


class MyModel(Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=64)
    objects = MyModelManager()
```

In file `serializers.py`:

```
from rest_framework.serializers import ModelSerializer

from models import MyModel


class MyModelSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('name',)
```

However, this leads to an import cycle, since both files try to import each other. I could prevent this by making a local import:

```
class MyModelManager(Manager):
    @property
    def serializer_class(self):
        from ow_articlecode.import_cycle_serializers import MyModelSerializer
        return MyModelSerializer
```

However, this feels like a hack. What would be a proper solution to break this import cycle?

Comment: What is `MyModelManager` doing here?

Comment: Why does the manager need to declare a serializer_class?

Answer (score 0):

A [**`Manager`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/), has *no* `serializer_class` field. In fact a manager does not know anything about serialization. A manager is used to filter, create, etc. objects.

Your `models.py` thus should look like:

```
# app/models.py

from django.db.models import Manager, Model, CharField


class MyModelManager(Manager):
    # no serializer_class
    pass


class MyModel(Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=64)
```

The idea of `Model`s is that this defines your business logic, not the serialization, form, view, template logic.